# Javascript drop down button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to Javascript. I tried creating a drop down content using Javascript. Using ID to find the element works but not if I use ClassName to do the same. 
I cannot use ID because this HTML files are dynamically created and there can be multiple buttons of the sort. So using ID is not an option here.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .dropbtn {
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
      padding: 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .dropbtn:hover,
    .dropbtn:focus {
      background-color: #2980B9;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      min-width: 160px;
      overflow: auto;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
    
    .show {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .alert_banner {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      color: #666;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
      background: #e4e6e7;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
      border: #ccc 1px solid;
      -moz-border-radius: 3px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
    }
    
    .footer_style {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #666;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 120%;
    }
    
    h3 {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      color: #666;
      font-size: 12px;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
    }
    
    .table_style a:link {
      color: #666;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .table_style a:visited {
      color: #999999;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .table_style a:active,
    .table_style a:hover {
      color: #bd5a35;
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
    
    .table_style {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      color: #666;
      font-size: 12px;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
      background: #eaebec;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
      border: #ccc 1px solid;
      -moz-border-radius: 3px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
    }
    
    .table_style th {
      padding: 21px 25px 22px 25px;
      border-top: 1px solid #fafafa;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #FF8300;
      border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
      background: #ededed;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ededed), to(#ebebeb));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ededed, #ebebeb);
    }
    
    .table_style th:first-child {
      text-align: left;
      padding-left: 20px;
    }
    
    .table_style tr:first-child th:first-child {
      -moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
      -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
      border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    }
    
    .table_style tr:first-child th:last-child {
      -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
      -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
      border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    }
    
    .table_style tr {
      text-align: center;
      padding-left: 20px;
    }
    
    .table_style td:first-child {
      text-align: left;
      padding-left: 20px;
      border-left: 0;
    }
    
    .table_style td {
      padding: 18px;
      border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
      border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
      background: #fafafa;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fbfbfb), to(#fafafa));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fbfbfb, #fafafa);
    }
    
    .table_style tr.even td {
      background: #f6f6f6;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f8f8f8), to(#f6f6f6));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8, #f6f6f6);
    }
    
    .table_style tr:last-child td {
      border-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    .table_style tr:last-child td:first-child {
      -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 3px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    }
    
    .table_style tr:last-child td:last-child {
      -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 3px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    }
    
    .table_style tr:hover td {
      background: #F2F2F2;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#F2F2F2), to(#f0f0f0));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F2F2F2, #f0f0f0);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementByClassName("dropdown-content").classList.toggle("show");
    }

    // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
  <center style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="bodyTable" style="table-layout:fixed; max-width:100% !important; width:100% !important; min-width: 100% !important;">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" id="bodyCell">
          <table bgcolor="#F2F2F2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;">
            <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="top">
                <table bgcolor="#F2F2F2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="color:#666;">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                  [IMAGE]
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="top">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                      <table class="alert_banner" bgcolor="#ebeef2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                        <tr>
                          <td valign="top" width="600">
                            <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                <td align="middle" valign="middle" width="60">
                                  <table bgcolor="red" border="0" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" width="60" style="max-width: 100%;border-radius:3px;">
                                    <tr>
                                      <td align="middle">
                                        <img src="http://images.arubathena.com/sys_notifications_email_image_1202.png" />
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                                <td align="left" valign="middle">
                                  <table border="0" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" style="max-width: 100%;">
                                    <tr>
                                      <td align="left">
                                        <h3 style="color:#666;line-height:125%;font-size:18px;font-weight:normal;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:3px;text-align:left;">
                                          <strong> Test Report</strong>
                                        </h3>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="top">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                      <table class="" bgcolor="#f2f2f2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                        <tr>
                          <td valign="top" width="600">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                  Tenant ID :102
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="top">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                <td valign="top" bgcolor="#F2F2F2">
                                  <div class="footer_style" style="text-align:left;">
                                    <div><span style="color:#666;">$report_body</span></div>
                                  </div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="top">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="30" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                  <table style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; border=collapse: collapse; width: 50%; border: blue 1px solid;">
                                    <tr>
                                      <td valign="top">
                                        <p style="text-align:left;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:15px;margin-bottom:0;color:#666;line-height:24px;">
                                          <tr style="order: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: justify; padding: 8px;">
                                            <th style=" border: blue 1px solid;" bgcolor="blue">TEST CASE</th>
                                            <th style=" border: blue 1px solid;" bgcolor="blue"> RESULT
                                              <th>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td align="center">
                                              <div class="dropdown"><button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">login</button>
                                                <div class="dropdown-content"> <a> Go to URL Success </a>
                                                  <a> T1 Success </a>
                                                  <a> T2 Success </a>
                                                  <a> T3 Success </a>
                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="center">PASS</td>
                                          </tr>
                                  </table>
                                  </td>
                                  </tr>
                            </table>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                      </table>
                      </td>
                      </tr>
                </table>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" valign="top">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                            <tr>
                              <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
          </table>
          </td>
          </tr>
    </table>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Can someone please go through the code and tell where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

P.S: This works.

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropDown").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

where as this doesn't work.

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementByClassName("dropdown-content").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Please add your code into your question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50853594/edit) it.

Comment: Please post your code in Codepen or in a similar playground environment: https://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: You have `document.getElementById("myDropdown")` but the id is `myDropDown`

Comment: Question edited.

Answer (score -1):

Replace your code with this:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .dropbtn {
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
      padding: 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .dropbtn:hover,
    .dropbtn:focus {
      background-color: #2980B9;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      min-width: 160px;
      overflow: auto;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
    
    .show {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .alert_banner {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      color: #666;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
      background: #e4e6e7;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
      border: #ccc 1px solid;
      -moz-border-radius: 3px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
    }
    
    .footer_style {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #666;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 120%;
    }
    
    h3 {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      color: #666;
      font-size: 12px;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
    }
    
    .table_style a:link {
      color: #666;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .table_style a:visited {
      color: #999999;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .table_style a:active,
    .table_style a:hover {
      color: #bd5a35;
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
    
    .table_style {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      color: #666;
      font-size: 12px;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff;
      background: #eaebec;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
      border: #ccc 1px solid;
      -moz-border-radius: 3px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
    }
    
    .table_style th {
      padding: 21px 25px 22px 25px;
      border-top: 1px solid #fafafa;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #FF8300;
      border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
      background: #ededed;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ededed), to(#ebebeb));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ededed, #ebebeb);
    }
    
    .table_style th:first-child {
      text-align: left;
      padding-left: 20px;
    }
    
    .table_style tr:first-child th:first-child {
      -moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
      -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
      border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    }
    
    .table_style tr:first-child th:last-child {
      -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
      -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
      border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    }
    
    .table_style tr {
      text-align: center;
      padding-left: 20px;
    }
    
    .table_style td:first-child {
      text-align: left;
      padding-left: 20px;
      border-left: 0;
    }
    
    .table_style td {
      padding: 18px;
      border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
      border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
      background: #fafafa;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fbfbfb), to(#fafafa));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fbfbfb, #fafafa);
    }
    
    .table_style tr.even td {
      background: #f6f6f6;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f8f8f8), to(#f6f6f6));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f8f8f8, #f6f6f6);
    }
    
    .table_style tr:last-child td {
      border-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    .table_style tr:last-child td:first-child {
      -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 3px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    }
    
    .table_style tr:last-child td:last-child {
      -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 3px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    }
    
    .table_style tr:hover td {
      background: #F2F2F2;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#F2F2F2), to(#f0f0f0));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F2F2F2, #f0f0f0);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }

    // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
  <center style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="bodyTable" style="table-layout:fixed; max-width:100% !important; width:100% !important; min-width: 100% !important;">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" id="bodyCell">
          <table bgcolor="#F2F2F2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;">
            <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="top">
                <table bgcolor="#F2F2F2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="color:#666;">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                  [IMAGE]
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="top">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                      <table class="alert_banner" bgcolor="#ebeef2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                        <tr>
                          <td valign="top" width="600">
                            <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                <td align="middle" valign="middle" width="60">
                                  <table bgcolor="red" border="0" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" width="60" style="max-width: 100%;border-radius:3px;">
                                    <tr>
                                      <td align="middle">
                                        <img src="http://images.arubathena.com/sys_notifications_email_image_1202.png" />
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                                <td align="left" valign="middle">
                                  <table border="0" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" style="max-width: 100%;">
                                    <tr>
                                      <td align="left">
                                        <h3 style="color:#666;line-height:125%;font-size:18px;font-weight:normal;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:3px;text-align:left;">
                                          <strong> Test Report</strong>
                                        </h3>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="top">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                      <table class="" bgcolor="#f2f2f2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                        <tr>
                          <td valign="top" width="600">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                  Tenant ID :102
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="top">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                <td valign="top" bgcolor="#F2F2F2">
                                  <div class="footer_style" style="text-align:left;">
                                    <div><span style="color:#666;">$report_body</span></div>
                                  </div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="top">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="30" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                  <table style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; border=collapse: collapse; width: 50%; border: blue 1px solid;">
                                    <tr>
                                      <td valign="top">
                                        <p style="text-align:left;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:15px;margin-bottom:0;color:#666;line-height:24px;">
                                          <tr style="order: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: justify; padding: 8px;">
                                            <th style=" border: blue 1px solid;" bgcolor="blue">TEST CASE</th>
                                            <th style=" border: blue 1px solid;" bgcolor="blue"> RESULT
                                              <th>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td align="center">
                                              <div class="dropdown"><button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">login</button>
                                                <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content"> <a> Go to URL Success </a>
                                                  <a> T1 Success </a>
                                                  <a> T2 Success </a>
                                                  <a> T3 Success </a>
                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="center">PASS</td>
                                          </tr>
                                  </table>
                                  </td>
                                  </tr>
                            </table>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                      </table>
                      </td>
                      </tr>
                </table>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" valign="top">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                            <tr>
                              <td align="center" valign="top" width="600">
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
          </table>
          </td>
          </tr>
    </table>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```